# How can I deal with having to code classic ASP?

Tags: ide, asp-classic, vbscript

I've just accepted a classic ASP project, because I need the work and the pay is good.  So, can I use Visual Studio >= 2005 to edit this?  Are there other editors that can deal with it, such as Aptana, NetBeans?  Are there add-ins to other editors that allow them to deal with it?  I don't want to go back to Visual Studio 6, because these days I find that quite a hateful product.  b

Comment: Binge-drinking comes to mind.

Comment: @joel, I was about to say `with a bottle of whiskey by your side`

Comment: @ProfK: Use the tool better suited to the language. For ASP, Visual Interdev comes to mind. I am not sure of VS.net support for classic ASP (atleast the ide developers wouldn't think of supporting that). do you need an editor for classic ASP? if so, why?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: A large part of ASP work is writing HTML, Visual Studion helps with that.  Also CSS files, Visual Studio helps with that.  Personanly I use a lot XSLT in my classic ASP work, Visual Studio helps with what.  An ASP web site is made up of multiple files and often folders that need managing, Visual Studio helps with that.  ASP Script execution needs debugging, Vistual Studio helps with that.  Need I go on...?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I am sorry, did I say anything different? Interdev had better support for classic ASP related project. Not sure, what you are trying to say by repeating "visual studio helps with that"? I know it already & said the same. Didn't I?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: "do you need an editor for classic ASP? if so, why?" perhaps I mis-read this question but it seemed to indicate that you question the need for a specific editor for ASP.  Interdev is rubbish to unusable when connected to current implementations of IIS.  It certainly doesn't give any overwhelming advantage that you'd want to install it when you've already got VS2005/8.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I have not used VS.net for classic asp projects & features such as debugging & project organization. So, I cannot comment on that. For me, VS interdev worked well in the past. I commented based on my experience & you seem to have done the same. Not sure, where we disagree? :)

Comment: @shahkalpesh:  I suspect we don't actually disagree. Short Text based communication hides shades of meaning that causes mis-understandings. (And I was already feeling irritated at the time, sorry). :)

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: No problem. Atleast, I learnt something from you - that one can use vs.net for asp based projects as well. Thanks!!

Comment: Everyone can learn a stack of stuff from Anthony, I think he has the whole of MSDN tatooed on this body!

Comment: Note that this question had already been asked two months prior: [A good IDE for classic ASP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742472/a-good-ide-for-classic-asp/41942147#41942147).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've worked extensively with ASP-Classic and ASP.NET for many years and I can categorically state that without question the best way to edit and debug ASP Classic code remains Visual Studio (2005 & 2008, I have yet test the experience in 2010 yet).

If you have VS2005 or VS2008 then by all means go ahead and use it.

Sorry if this sounds a bit dogmatic but I do tend to get a little irritated with the "Edit it text editor, debug it with Response.Write" crowd.  Its simply isn't necessary and is very painful.  Its true that debugging ASP is not as slick as ASP.NET (you can't just press the "run" button) but its close, much closer than many people seem to think.

Comment: Not dogmatic at all Anthony, we all use what tools we have at hand and alot of ASP devs back in the day (and therefore is alot of the articles) don't have Visual Studio installed so Response.Writes where the way to go.

Comment: Very of topic but in a answer a while back (which I can't find) you where talking about the Free Threaded DOM Document object. You went on to recommend a few versions of MSXML but to skip some others. What is that choice based on? Which is best of the versions and why? I think you said three was pretty much on every server but use 6 if you can (but its not always available). Just interested.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I tend to do classic ASP in a straight text editor, like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm). Both have good syntax highlighting for ASP, and I don't think an IDE buys you as much with classic ASP as it does with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3):

I too program in classic ASP in a straight text editor (using the web creation program I developed myself - Sitestepper, which contains StepEdit with full syntax highlighting for classic ASP and a possibility to easily make multi language versions of your ASP code).

Since I am a web developer myself, the program is I developed is aimed at web and asp development with little smart tricks to make my work easier.

If anyone is interested in this program, drop me a not info at edelcom dot be. I don't want to push it here but I know for certain it has its merits. Knowing that I do web development myself half of the time, you can imagine that it make sence to make the program as workable as possible (within my limits of programmer and time I can spend on the development). It is aimed more at the technical programmer (as myself), than at end users. It has a limited user base, but the people who use it, use it to maintain and develop sites with multiple languages and hundreds of pages.

Comment: I noticed some one downvoted my answer. I wish they would say why. Most probably because I was talking about my own software in my anwswer. That is funny: if you mention an editor like Notepad++ and others, you get an upvote, but just because I wrote one myself and mention that, you get downvoted. If you are developers, wound't you wish you had the source of your editors , so that you could enhance it anyway you want ? I certainly would, and I did.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try Dreamweaver if you have it.  It handles Classic ASP and even provides some Code Completion.

Comment: That is what i usually use too ..

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio (2005 or 2008) is good with classic ASP; and the intelisense (although limited) will be of use if you're not yet 'fluent' in classic asp.

Or if you want to get raw with the code; textpad is good and free.

Answer (score 1):

I have to do ASP Classic a lot at my work :( I use Textpad it seems to do a fine job. Honestly you don't get much out of using an IDE with ASP Classic

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio, use it.
Otherwise, MS Expression Web (aka Frontpage) does a passable job.

Comment: *shudder @ the mention of Frontpage*

Comment: @Pete, yes, shudder.  Expression is a whole lot better.

Answer (score 0):

I have used an editor called [Primal Script](http://sapien.com), which has syntax highlighting.  In addition it has rather good intellisense and can be configured for degugging.  It is proprietary though.  I have also used Notepad++ which is not bad, specially if you mix the templates for VB script and ASP.