# How to enable intellisense and syntax highlighting for classic ASP in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp-classic, intellisense

This is the situation. I'm currently working on very old project in Visual Studio 2013. The app was coded by previous developer using classic ASP and the language is visual basic. Now, I'm writing the code live at development server using FTP connection from my PC. However, the ASP syntax highlighting and intellisense is not working which make me very unproductive. I've tried several solution but none work for me so far. Is there any workaround?

Comment: You are not first who asking such question. Looks like it's impossible to have intellisense and syntax highlight in VS2013 like in old VS.NET

Comment: yeah you are right. :(

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 and it works just fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013:
From main menu: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension
add extension "ASP" and select Automatic Editor Selector (XML) and press add
[image]

and some users listed that they didn't like VS with ASP, check there: [A good IDE for classic ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742472/a-good-ide-for-classic-asp)